# Object.create(http.ServerResponse.prototype) is undefiened

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm trying use express to connect database mysql .
But i received notify error.I installed library express by `npm install express` and mysql by `npm install mysql`.
And I tryed remove library after install many times again but it not working.
Now, I don't know how to make it work.
This is notify error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/Administrator/ReactJS-Project/firstreactweb/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:42
  39 |  * @public
  40 |  */
  41 | 
> 42 | var res = Object.create(http.ServerResponse.prototype)
  43 | 
  44 | /**
  45 |  * Module exports.
View compiled
./node_modules/express/lib/response.js
http://localhost:3000/vendors~main.cba83766a7fd60fd416a.hot-update.js:41530:30
```

And that is my code.

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const app = express();
```

I try search for google and stack but I recived answer is due to automatically `import reponse from 'express'` but I checked top line but i haven't import it. Can anyone help me fix that error!

Comment: `http.ServerRespons` is `undefined`. Check what `http` is.

Comment: What node.js version and what express version do you have installed?

Comment: This may help: https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3659#issuecomment-768412388

Comment: @VLAZ `http.ServerRepons` it is line 42 syntax in reponse.js which it is file in library `express` of the React. So I don't know what it is.

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc i seen it. But i haven't `import reponse from 'express'`

Comment: Try to search in the whole project. May be you have unintended import somewhere.

Comment: @Bergi  My version express is 4.17.1 and nodejs version is 14.16.0

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc i checked whole project . I haven't unintended import anywhere.

Comment: @ChiếnNguyễnVăn Cuong has linked the right issue. Also from the error message it appears that you are loading `express` in one of your frontend modules - either with `import` or with `require`. You can only use express on the server side, in node.js.

Comment: @Bergi exactly! I'm using it in my fronted modules.

Comment: @ChiếnNguyễnVăn Well that can't work :-)

Comment: @Bergi So that can just frontend site impact data by fetch or axios??

Comment: @Bergi thanks for so much that help makes me understand more.

Answer (score 0):

MYSQL is a server-side lib, and doesn't have any use in the client (browser). Bundling and optimizing js files is (in general) only for client-side JavaScript and not server-side JavaScript. So you do not need to bundle anything to run your Node.js server.

Some things depend on features that are available to Node.js but are not available in browsers (such the networking features required to connect to MySQL or run an HTTP server). Those need the JS to be run under Node.js and not a browser.